# Wordpress - Use image from URL as a post thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins

I want to use an external image from URL as a post thumbnail, BUT **I don't want to download and store the image in my server**

I'm found this code in other guy question:

```
        $filename = "thumbnail_".$post_id".jpg";
        $upload_file = wp_upload_bits( $filename, null, @file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.jpg') );

        if ( ! $upload_file['error'] ) {
          $filename = $upload_file['file'];
          $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );

          $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_parent'    => $post_id,
            'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename ),
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
          file_put_contents('attachment_id.txt', print_r($attachment_id, true));

          if ( ! is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
              require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

              $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
              wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
              set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
          }
        }
```

It downloads the image to my server and also duplicates the image file in my uploads directory (I don't know why)

But I don't wanna download the image how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this image is just alternative to the featured image - you could store the URL of the image source in the custom field.

`add_post_meta( $post_id, 'image', 'http://example.com/image.jpg' );`

Then you can retrieve this URL anywhere you need to.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to retrieve like: `get_post_meta( the_ID(), 'image',true ); ?>` but it returns the actual post ID not the image url, any idea?

Comment: I put the code here: `<img src="<?php get_post_meta( the_ID(), 'image',true ); ?>" />`

Comment: `the_ID()` should be `get_the_ID()`

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: This does work but your question was originally asking to add an external image URL as the assigned post_thumbnail/attachement.  This is post meta data and not technically the  post thumbnail.  If you use the_thumbnail() this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but assuming you're always going to want the same file, this may help get you started:

```
$filepath = 'http://example.com/'; //Change this to the actual file path...
$filename = 'image.jpg'; //Change this to the actual file name...
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
$attachment = array(
    'guid'              => $filepath . $filename,
    'post_mime_type'    => $filetype['type'],
    'post_parent'       => $post_id,
    'post_title'        => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename ),
    'post_content'      => '',
    'post_status'       => 'inherit'
);
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
if( !is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
}
```

Comment: This will still download the image. He doesn't want that.

Comment: I didn't test it myself, but out of curiosity, where is this still downloading and uploading the image?   It's mean to write the external URL and file to the GUID field and create a new attachment post and associate it with an existing post.  There's nothing in the code that downloads or uploads.

Comment: `wp_insert_attachment` will add this image to the library. By all means, your code isn't wrong - it's just not what mentamarindo asked for. When I get a minute I will test your code and see if a unique URL can be registered with the image without getting it on to the hosting.

Comment: From my reading of the question I took it as specifically wanting to associate the URL as the post_thumbnail - I've always done it the way you do, adding it as post_meta if I want to add an alternative image.  I'd test myself but I'm absolutely swamped. LOL!

Comment: I think there is a way of changing the image source URL and having it still in the library. The S3 Offload Media does it somehow. So much work going on - UP THE WALLs!